# how to split, remove part of data in column with ;

Tags: ruby, string

I am using the Spreadsheet gem.

My code is:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open 'excel-file.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet 0
book.write 'output-file.xls'
```

I want to remove data that comes after "`;`" in a column:

```
FULTON BANK NA;FULTON BANK
```

I just want it to be `FULTON BANK NA` for example.

Also, I want to leave price data like this: `$78,000.00` and want to strip
all other data from a specific column:

```
MORTGAGE - CORPORATE;($78,000.00)
```

I just want it to be `$78,000.00` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
s = 'FULTON BANK NA;FULTON BANK'
s = s[/[^;]+/]
```

that will leave every before the first semicolon in `s`. Or you could it like this:

```
s = s.split(';')[0]
```

Or

```
s.gsub!(/;.*/, '')  # This modifies s in place
```

For the second one, it depends on the format of your data but you could start with this:

```
s = 'MORTGAGE - CORPORATE;($78,000.00)'
s = s[/\(([^)]+)\)/, 1]
```

Or, if the last component may or may not have parentheses, you could do something like this:

```
s = s.split(';')[-1].tr('()', '')
```

That will split `s` into pieces at the semicolons (`split(';')`), take the last component (`[-1]`), and then remove any parentheses that there (`.tr('()', '')`).

Comment: thanks mu, I see it is working ok in rails itself but the changes are not shown in exported excel file. also it returns null for the cells that does not include ";" (semicolon) any ideas why it could be so?

Comment: @user848316: You could do things like `s = s[/[^;]+/] || s` or `column = column.to_s.gsub(/;.*/, '')` to get around the `nil` problem. Then you'd need to replace the old value with the new value in the spreadsheet.

Comment: hey there again.. I donot know why, when I am doing some stuff with spreadsheet gem like hiding couple of columns, itonly works when I include this code:  format = Spreadsheet::Format.new   sheet.row(2).default_format = format   otherwise not working

Comment: @ghaydarov: Sorry, I haven't used the spreadsheet gem that much and I've only used it to read spreadsheets. Try asking another question, there's probably someone around that knows more about it than I do.